# How do I find vowels in a string, and print the word with the most vowels on the screen?

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I need to find all vowels in a user inputted string, and then print the word with the most vowels on the screen.
The program uses user input.
The user types in a string of words in lowercase.
e.g.

> "I like java programming"

and it should read out:

> programming

I tried splitting the string into different words, and that works.
I only don't know how to apply a "for" loop to search in the different words.
I need to work in methods, so this is the method I used to find vowels in the string:

```
public void findvowel(){
    for(int index = 0;index < word.length();index++){
    char vowel = word.charAt(index);
    if( (vowel == 'a')||
        (vowel == 'e')||
        (vowel == 'i')||
        (vowel == 'o')||
        (vowel == 'u')){
            System.out.println(vowel);
            }
        }
    }
```

But I know this doesn't work. 
Can you people help me?

Comment: I might be missing something obvious, but this function looks like it should work fine.  However you might want to make it clear where the `word` variable comes from.  I would have expected it to be an argument to the `findvowel` method.

Comment: Why do you think this doesn't work?

Comment: Can you show a simple input and expected output you are looking for?

Comment: Lately people are posting working code and see imaginary bugs.

Comment: If you want to **count** a number of vowels then create a variable to hold  it, initialize it to zero and increment it inside your `if`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Compare OP's code with the requirements. The code runs, but does it produce the required **result**?

Answer (score 5):

```
public class MaxVowels {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "This is a loooooooooong sentence";
        int maxVowelCount = 0;
        String wordsWithMostVowels = null;
        String[] words = sentence.split(" ");

        for(String word : words){
            int vowelCount = 0;
            word = word.toLowerCase();
            for(int i = 0; i < word.length() ; i++){
                char x = word.charAt(i);
                if(x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' ||
                   x == 'o' || x == 'u'){
                    vowelCount++;
                }
            }
            if(vowelCount > maxVowelCount){
                maxVowelCount = vowelCount;
                wordsWithMostVowels = word;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Word with most vowels is: " + wordsWithMostVowels);
    }
}
```

The code is fairly straightforward and needs no explanation =)
The code ignores the case where two words have the same number of vowels. In this case, the first word will be used as the word with most vowels.

Comment: If anyone is interested, here is this code translated to Go and runnable: http://play.golang.org/p/o-3RpXWQoA

Answer (score 1):

This should be a good starting point; note that the method name now really says what it does -

```
// public static int findvowel(String word) {
public static int getVowelCount(String word) {
  int count = 0;
  if (word != null) {
    word = word.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
  if (word == null || word.length() < 1) {
    return count;
  }
  for (int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++) {
    // That Fred he's a
    char fred = word.charAt(index);
    if ((fred == 'a') || (fred == 'e')
        || (fred == 'i') || (fred == 'o')
        || (fred == 'u')) {
      ++count;
      }
  }
  System.out.println("For the word \"" + word
      + "\" there are " + count + " vowels");
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Not all OP requirements are implemented.  Which is fine with me since SO is **not** a "*do my homework for me service*".

Comment: I was just trying to give a pointer in the right direction. I renamed "vowel" to fred, but otherwise it's OP's code (only fixed to return a count). :)

Comment: In my (not so humble opinion) this is the right approach. It would've even better that you were providing a starting point and not the whole answer. +1 to you.

Answer (score 1):

You're going in the right direction. Few things:

You don't need to print vowels. You will be counting number of vowels in all the words. As you will be doing it one word at a time, you want to remember counts for words that came earlier. A better strategy is to remember only the word having maximum number of vowels. Whenever you find a word with more vowels, you update your result.

You can use *fields* to remember the word with maximum number of vowels along with the number:

```
String wordWithMaxVowels;
int maxNumberOfVowels;
```

Suppose at this instance you're working on a single `word`. You need a *local* variable to keep a count of vowels in this `word`.

```
int vowelCount = 0;
// Your code to loop over the word but remember
// to increase vowelCount if you find a vowel:
// vowelCount++;
```

Finally the check to see if this number is greater than the maximum we have so far. Update the fields if that's the case:

```
if(vowelCount > maxNumberOfVowels) {
    wordWithMaxVowels = word;
    maxNumberOfVowels = vowelCount;
}
```

Another tip follows. To check if a character `c` is a vowel, you can:

```
if ("aeiouAEIOU".indexOf(c) != -1) {
    vowelCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your findVowel() method is almost there.  Why are you outputting the vowels when you're supposed to count them instead?   Instead of findVowel(), i think you want something called countVowels()  that returns the amount of vowels in a word.  Something like this:

```
    public int countVowels(String word){
      int count = 0;
      for(int index = 0;index < word.length();index++){
        char vowel = word.charAt(index);
        if( (vowel == 'a')||
                (vowel == 'e')||
                (vowel == 'i')||
                (vowel == 'o')||
                (vowel == 'u')){
            count++;
        }
      }
      return count;
    }
```

this way, you can call countVowels() on every word in the sentence, and keep track of the word with the most vowels so far.
Ex:

```
String sentence = "This is a sentence.";
String[] words = sentence.split(" ");  //splits sentence into string array by spaces

String maxStringSoFar = "";
int maxStringVowelCount = 0;
for(String s : words)
{
     int currentWordVowelCount = countVowels(s);
     if(currentWordVowelCount > maxStringVowelCount)
     {
          maxStringSoFar = s;
          maxStringVowelCount = currentWordVowelCount;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have some Different answer-----

```
class strDemo2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    String s1=new String("The Ghost of The Arabean Sea");


        char c1[]=new char[30];
        char c2[]={'a','e','i','o','u'}; 
         s1.getChars(0,28,c1,0);
         int pf=0,pl=0;
        for(int i=0;i<s1.length();i++)
        {
           for(int j=0;j<5;j++) 
           {
              if(c1[i]==c2[j])   
              {
          System.out.println("vowel found at:-> "+(i+1)+" which is "+c2[j]);
              }    
           }  
        }               

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test2{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String message = "words containig mooooost vowels";
    String wordWithMostVowel = null;
    int maxVowelCount = 0;
    String tests[] = message.split(" ");
    int totalVowel = 0;
    for(String test : tests){
        int vowelCount = 0;
        test = test.toLowerCase();
        for(int i=0;i<test.length();i++){
            switch(test.charAt(i)){
            case 'a':
            case 'e':
            case 'i':
            case 'o':
            case 'u':
            vowelCount++;
            }
            if(vowelCount > maxVowelCount){
                maxVowelCount = vowelCount;
                wordWithMostVowel = test;
            }
        }
        totalVowel = totalVowel+vowelCount;
    }
    System.out.println("total vowels "+totalVowel+" word with max vowel is "+wordWithMostVowel);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Vowels(){
        String Name = "seleniumtesting";
        String Vowels = "aeiou";
        char[] N = Name.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0; i<N.length; i++){

            if(Vowels.contains(String.valueOf(N[i]))){
                System.out.println("It is a Vowel : "+ N[i]);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please explain your awnser. It makes it much easier for the OP to understand what he has done wrong. Here is a little guide for you: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer