# Checking vowels in string array

Tags: java, arrays

This is the code I have written to count the amount of vowels in a string array:

```
int vowels = 0;
for (int x = 0; x < arrayInput.length; x++) {
    for (int a = 0; a < arrayInput[x].length(); a++){
        switch (arrayInput[x].charAt(a)){
            case 'A': vowels++;
            case 'a': vowels++;
            case 'E': vowels++;
            case 'e': vowels++;
            case 'I': vowels++;
            case 'i': vowels++;
            case 'O': vowels++;
            case 'o': vowels++;
            case 'U': vowels++;
            case 'u': vowels++;
            case 'Y': vowels++;
            case 'y': vowels++;
        }
    }
}
```

However, vowels always returns 0. Why?

Found the problem!
This code earlier in the program:

```
String[] vowelArray = arrayInput;
for (int x = 0; x < vowelArray.length; x++) {
    vowelArray[x] = vowelArray[x].replaceAll("[AEIOUYaeiouy]", "_");
}
for (int x = 0; x < vowelArray.length; x++) {
    System.out.print(vowelArray[x] + " ");
}
```

Was changing the value of `arrayInput'
Does anyone know why?

Comment: You need to use `break` after each case. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: Please show the contents of your `String` array.

Comment: I posted [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19986654/how-do-i-find-vowels-in-a-string-and-print-the-word-with-the-most-vowels-on-the/19986883#19986883) yesterday.  You should check it out.

Comment: You should print the contain of `arrayInput[x]` to make sure it isn't empty.

Comment: What do you mean by - "Was changing the value of `arrayInput' Does anyone know why?" ?? also OP stands for Original Poster.

Comment: @AnkitRustagi It also stands for Original Post. What I mean is that it was putting the new value of `vowelArray` into `arrayInput`

Answer (score 4):

The code works fine, check if `arrayInput` is not empty/null and yes add break statements

```
    String[] arrayInput = {"This","is","random","string"};
    int vowels = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < arrayInput.length; x++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < arrayInput[x].length(); a++){
            switch (arrayInput[x].charAt(a)){
                case 'A': vowels++;break;
                case 'a': vowels++;break;
                case 'E': vowels++;break;
                case 'e': vowels++;break;
                case 'I': vowels++;break;
                case 'i': vowels++;break;
                case 'O': vowels++;break;
                case 'o': vowels++;break;
                case 'U': vowels++;break;
                case 'u': vowels++;break;
                case 'Y': vowels++;break;
                case 'y': vowels++;break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(vowels);
```

Output

```
5
```

Input

```
"This"   "is"    "random"    "string"
   -      -        -  -          -
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the `break;` statement after each case block. Because you want the vovels to count but if the case statement ever reaches it continue to execute and count other cases. But your case is never reached. Thus having wrong conditions.

Comment: had that been the case, then he surely wouldnt have got 0, right ?

Comment: @AnkitRustagi No, it's not possible to do like you.